# Phonegap: Android 6 status bar overlaps webview

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I built an app with PhoneGap for Android. It works fine untill you open any text input - after that status bar overlaps webview and stays there.

Ive searched all questions and seems like its a common problem for iOS 7, but not for Android. And no menthions of phonegap issues whatsoever.

[Before touching input field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxZX2.png)

[After touching input field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6noH.png)

Any ideas how to override it for Andorid built in Phonegap?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There was fullscreen enabled by default in config.xml

Disabled it and now it works without overlapping:

```
<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
```