# Phonegap build Status bar overlaps webview in Fullscreen Mode

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I built an app with PhoneGap Build for Android. It works fine until you open any text input - after that status bar overlaps webview and stays there.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxZX2.png 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6noH.png

This is the same question like this one
[Phonegap: Android 6 status bar overlaps webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35126192/phonegap-android-6-status-bar-overlaps-webview)

but i don't want to disable the Full-Screenmode.

I think it is not possible to force to disable the Fullscreen mode (all the time). Right?

If so:
My idea/workaround is to hide the statusBar after focus out. 
If this possible with phonegab build?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**My workaround:** 
add this to your `config.xml`

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" source="npm"/>
```

and add this to your in your js file

```
$(document).click(function()
{
    StatusBar.hide();                 
});
```